# Passing multiple dictionary observations to function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How would I pass multiple dictionary observations (row) into function for model prediction?

This is what I have ... it can accept 1 dictionary row as input and returns the prediction + probabilities, but fails when adding additional dictionaries.

```py
import json

# func
def preds(dict):
    df = pd.DataFrame([dict])
    result = model.predict(df)
    result = np.where(result==0,"CLASS_0","CLASS_1").astype('str')
    probas_c0 = model.predict_proba(df)[0][0]
    probas_c1 = model.predict_proba(df)[0][1]
    data={"prediction": result[0],
                      "CLASS_0_PROB": probas_c0,
                      "CLASS_1_PROB": probas_c1}
    data = {"parameters": [data]}
    j = json.dumps(data)
    j = json.loads(j)
    return j

# call func
preds({"feature0": "value",
  "feature1": "value",
  "feature2": "value"})

# result
{'parameters': [{'prediction': 'CLASS_0',
   'CLASS_0_PROB': 0.9556067383610446,
   'CLASS_1_PROB': 0.0443932616389555}]}
```

```py
# Tried with more than 1 row but it fails with arguments error
{'parameters': [{'prediction': 'CLASS_0',
   'CLASS_0_PROB': 0.9556067383610446,
   'CLASS_1_PROB': 0.0443932616389555},
 {'parameters': [{'prediction': 'CLASS_0',
   'CLASS_0_PROB': 0.9556067383610446,
   'CLASS_1_PROB': 0.0443932616389555}]}

TypeError: preds() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

## NEW UPDATE

The source data format from end users will most likely be a dataframe so want to convert that to format of [{...},{...}] so it can be plugged into `preds()` function here `df=pd.DataFrame([rows])`

Tried this so far...

```py
rows = [
{"c1": "value1",
  "c2": "value2",
  "c3": 0,
},
{"c1": "value1,
  "c2": "value2,
  "c3": 0}
]

df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
json_rows = df.to_json(orient='records',  lines=True)
l = [json_rows]
preds(l)

KeyError: "None of [['c1', 'c2', 'c3']] are in the [columns]"
```

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED**

Ok, based on your commentaries, what you need is the DataFrame get all rows, then you can use the next aproachs

Using `*args`

```
def preds(*args):
     # args is tuple you need to cast as list
     dict_rows = list(args)
     df = pd.DataFrame(dict_rows)
     result = model.predict(df)
     ...

# calling the function you need to unpack
preds(*rows)
```

Checking the element beforehand

```
def preds(dict_rows):
    # checking if dict_rows is a list or a dict
    if isinstance(dict_rows, dict)
        dict_rows = [dict_rows]
    df = pd.DataFrame(dict_rows)
    result = model.predict(df)
    ...

# For calling you need to
preds(rows)
```

Please note that `pd.DataFrame(dict_rows)` not accepting `[dict]`.

**Old Anwser**

If `preds()` can't handle multiple rows you can do

```
pred_rows = [
     {"feature0": "value","feature1": "value", "feature2": "value"}
     {"feature3": "value","feature4": "value", "feature5": "value"}
]
# List Comprehension
result = [preds(row) for row in pred_rows]
```

PS: also don't use `dict` as a variable name, is a [Mapping Type](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict), a constructor/class for dictionaries

Comment: thank you sir! ... this works, but is it the best approach?  would something like **kwargs or another type be better?

Comment: Its a pythonic approach, `**kwargs` will capture any keyword argument given to a function to be given as a dict (kwargs), that will not help. If you want to handle multiple positional arguments you use `*args`, calling your function like `preds(row_1, row_2, ...)` and needs to handle the logic for every argument

Comment: thank you ... basically I just want to pass multiple rows of data into my model function ... what you provided now achieves this but if there is a better approach i am all in

Comment: You need the `DataFrame` use every row?

Comment: yes it would be a ```DataFrame``` source so I could convert it to json and pass it into the function to make predictions ... this is my current idea

Comment: ok so what I am trying to do is if I have a dataframe ```df``` need to convert to this format ```[{...},{...}]``` so a list with json/dict structure per element.  when i perform ```df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
json_rows = df.to_json(orient='records',  lines=True)``` the ```json_rows``` object is a string of json ... any ideas?

Comment: added a new update ... should be straight forward ... just having some trouble